# How To Get Clicked Geometry’s Name Attribute From BufferGeometry in ThreeJS?

Tags: three.js, buffer-geometry

I’m developing a VueJs application and added 1000 box model to the scene. Although I’ve set the every geometry’s name attribute when I clicked the box model I couldn’t get the box geometry’s name. I think this is caused by applying merged buffer geometry. Is it possible to get name attribute by clicking in some way ?

Here is my code;

```
addCubeToScene() {
  this.oDracoLoader = new DRACOLoader();
  this.oDracoLoader.setDecoderPath("./draco/");
  this.oGltfLoader = new GLTFLoader();
  this.oGltfLoader.setDRACOLoader(this.oDracoLoader);
  this.oDracoLoader.preload();
  this.oGltfLoader.load(BoxModel, function(oObject) {
    oObject.scene.traverse(function(oObject) {
      if (oObject.isMesh) {
        var oObjectGeometry = oObject.geometry;
        for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
          var oGeometry = oObjectGeometry.clone();
          oGeometry.applyMatrix4(
            new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(
              Math.random() * 3000,
              Math.random() * 5000,
              Math.random() * 1000
            )
          );
          oGeometry.name = "Box-" + i;
          oCubes.push(oGeometry);
        }
        var oGeometriesCubes = BufferGeometryUtils.mergeBufferGeometries(
          oCubes
        );
        oGeometriesCubes.computeBoundingSphere();
        const oTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(BoxTexture);
        oTexture.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
        var oMesh = new THREE.Mesh(
          oGeometriesCubes,
          new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
            map: oTexture,
            side: THREE.DoubleSide,
          })
          // new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial()
        );
        oMesh.scale.set(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
        oThis.scene.add(oMesh);
        oThis.renderScene();
      }
    });
  });
}

onMouseClick(oEvent) {
  oEvent.preventDefault();
  oEvent.stopPropagation();
  oMouse.x =
    (oEvent.offsetX / this.renderer.domElement.clientWidth) * 2 - 1;
  oMouse.y =
    -(oEvent.offsetY / this.renderer.domElement.clientHeight) * 2 + 1;
  oRaycaster.setFromCamera(oMouse, this.camera);
  var oIntersects = oRaycaster.intersectObjects(this.scene.children, true);
  if (oIntersects[0] && oIntersects[0].object) {
    var oObject = oIntersects[0].object;
    console.log(oObject); // I would like to get clicked geometry's name from this object
  }
}
```

Here is the image representing box model’s view;

[image]

Here is the result of box geometry datas

[image]

When I merged all geometries I can't see any name attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're trying to merge the geometry to increase render performance. While you did manage to reduce the number of draw calls the GPU had to make, you also removed all uniqueness of the different `BufferGeometry` objects. Your geometry is now represented by one big buffer (debug `oGeometriesCubes.attributes.position.array` to see this).

In the interest of performance, we can not only save you GPU draw calls, but also memory, *and* we can get your box picking to work as well. Let's start from scratch. It will seem like we've taken a step backward, but then it will all fall together...

#### Your geometry definitions

First, you do not need to uniquely identify each `BufferGeometry`. `Mesh` objects can share geometry! AND materials! This equates to memory savings.

Having unique `Mesh` objects also means you can put the `name` and translation information at the `Mesh` level. Translating at the geometry level 1000 times is *expensive*, even if you do it up-front like you do. Trust that the GPU can do these translations very quickly from the Mesh level. It's literally the GPU's job.

#### Your mesh definitions

Now, we're still looking at 1000 meshes, which means 1000 draw calls, right? That's where [`InstancedMesh`](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=instance#api/en/objects/InstancedMesh) comes into play.

Instancing--in *very* simple terms--is a way for the GPU to not only re-use the geometry buffer information, but also to perform the drawing of all 1000 meshes in a single swipe, rather than one at a time.

To sum it up:

- Using only one `BufferGeometry` object...
- And one material...
- We'll draw 1000 instances...
- In one draw call.

Ready? Let's do it.

#### The code

```js
let geometry = yourGeometryFromGLTF;
// load your texture here...
let material = new new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
  map: oTexture,
  side: THREE.DoubleSide,
})

let iMesh = new THREE.InstancedMesh( geometry, material, 1000 );

let translateMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
let scaleMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4().makeScale( 0.5, 0.5, 0.5 );
let finalMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();

for( let i = 0; i < 1000; ++i ){ 
 ​
  ​translateMatrix.makeTranslation(
    ​Math.random() * 1500,
    ​Math.random() * 2500,
    ​Math.random() * 500
 ​ );

  finalMatrix.multiplyMatrices( translateMatrix, scaleMatrix );
 ​ 
  iMesh.setMatrixAt( i, finalMatrix );

}

imesh.instanceMatrix.needsUpdate = true; // IMPORTANT
scene.add( iMesh );
```

Now your `Raycaster` should return the instances, but it will take one more step to get the "ID" of which box you selected.

```js
let intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene);
if(intersects.length > 0){
  let boxName = `Box-${ intersects[0].instanceId }`;
}
```

The `instanceId` will be the index of the box instance in your `InstancedMesh`. You can even use it to get more information about that instance, like its transformation matrix:

```js
let iMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
iMesh.getMatrixAt( intersects.instanceId, iMatrix );
```

Comment: Note, you probably don't need `finalMatrix` because you can just multiply the `scaleMatrix` onto the `translateMatrix`, then feed `translateMatrix` into `imesh.setMatrixAt`. But I left it the way that it is for clarity.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed clarification @TheJim01. I would like to ask a question about InstancedMesh. I've created an empty array and I've added every mesh to this array in for loop. But when I check this array I see that all meshes have same name property. So, when I clicked any mesh I can get the same name from my model. Where am I doing mistake ? If you can help me I would very appreciated.

Comment: Do I need to create InstancedMesh in every loop in order to access every mesh's name attribute by clicking process ?

Comment: @MLElyakan You are correct, I messed up, and I have corrected my answer. Your `Raycaster` will only ever return the single `InstancedMesh` from your scene. You will need to use the `instanceId` property of the `Raycaster`'s results to know which instance was hit.

Comment: Thanks for your support @TheJim01. Can I change position or rotation values from instanceId ? Additionally can I set user data for each instance ?

Comment: I would like to ask a question about getMatrixAt method. When I used this code it returns undefined. Do I need to set second parameter be able to get instance information at specific instance index ? I tried this code but I couldn't get any information. If you can help me I would very appreciated. let iMatrix = iMesh.getMatrixAt( intersects.instanceId );

Comment: I'm using this code but it gives an error. Could it be because of the threejs version?     var iMatrix = oMesh.getMatrixAt(oIntersects[0].instanceId, oMesh.instanceMatrix);

Comment: @MLElyakan Regarding `getMatrixAt`, please see my correction. I also linked to the `InstancedMesh` docs, but [here it is again](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=instance#api/en/objects/InstancedMesh). Regarding properties per instance, you would need to create a map of instance index to property bundle. That's a topic really worthy of its own question though.